# PeeWee Integer Primary Key needs force_insert=True

Tags: python, mysql, peewee

I am using the excellent `PeeWee` module to save some Ids and hostnames to a `MySQL` table.
I want the 'clientId' (which is an IntegerField) to be the primary key, but I seem to need to use `save(force_insert=True)` to make it insert - otherwise I get nothing added to the table. I don't get any error messages.
I thought this was only supposed to be needed if the primary_key field was NOT an Integer.
I am referring to the documentation - (https://peewee.readthedocs.org/en/2.0.2/peewee/fields.html#non-integer-primary-keys)

My Model:-

```
class BaseModel(peewee.Model):
    class Meta:
        database = db

class Client(BaseModel):
    clientId = peewee.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    clientName = peewee.TextField()
    isDeletedClient = peewee.BooleanField(default=False)

#Create object to insert using collected data...
clientEntry = Client(clientId=clientId, 
                     clientName=clientName, 
                     isDeletedClient=isDeletedClient)

#clientEntry.save()  # <-- Nothing gets inserted
clientEntry.save(force_insert=True)    # <-- Works.
```

---

Thankyou so much for responding. I believe that I was using the save() method incorrectly. Rather than save(), which can do an update if the record already exists with a primary key, I should have been using create(), because my script is always creating a new, empty table then populating it.

So now my model remains the same, but inserting a row becomes...

```
clientEntry = Client.create(clientId=clientId, 
                            clientName=clientName,
                            isDeletedClient=isDeletedClient)
```

Comment: *The way peewee determines whether to do an INSERT versus an UPDATE comes down to checking whether the primary key value is None. If None, it will do an insert, otherwise it does an update on the existing value.* So, is your `clientId` equal to `None`?

Comment: Hi, Geoff. Regardless to the docs http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/api.html#Model.save INSERT will be issued regardless of whether or not the primary key exists. I think you tried to insert record with existing primary key. You can try primary key with auto increment http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/api.html#PrimaryKeyField

Answer (score 3):

This is a subtle point, but if you want *auto incrementing* primary key fields, you should use `PrimaryKeyField` rather than `IntegerField(primary_key=True)`.

This should fix the issue:

```
class Client(BaseModel):
    clientId = peewee.PrimaryKeyField()
    clientName = peewee.TextField()
    isDeletedClient = peewee.BooleanField(default=False)
```